# How to install last version of ADT plug-in for eclipse

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I am interested in android. I use Eclipse with ADT plug-in and I have downloaded a project from GitHub site and trying to understand this.

But XML file can't be opened, the error message :

"This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in".

It seems that my ADT version is old for this recent project although I have installed v23.0.2.1.

I need help to reach the last version for ADT or another solution for my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using eclispe??

Comment: Yes..sorry I forget to say that

Comment: I would recommend using android studio, you can import the eclispe project (that you downloaded) to android studio, just need to search it in google on how to.

Comment: I tried to do this but so many errors appear

Comment: just make sure you do it right, or it might have some kind of library that android studio dont understand, you can find it in the libs folder of the eclispe project, if you can find some .jar file then you need to copy paste in the android studio project libs

Comment: Thanks I have to try this.but my question for last version for ADT .

Comment: On your Graphical  Layout  tag of your xml page ,there is a spinner with a green android robot and your SDK version on the top,choose a version lower would solve your problem

Comment: Sorry but I have 22API platform only.

Comment: Download more on your SDK manager dude ,SDK is for all Android development tools like studio or eclipse . At least 4.0 and higher.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Do you use `Eclipse ADT Bundle`, I mean - before `Android Studio 1.0` was released  there was ADT Bundle - Eclipse with additional Android tools.

Well I see, it's still available to download: http://tools.android.com/recent/eclipseadtbundleupdated

If you use it, please **delete it** and download clean Eclipse from this site:
https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Mars/1

If you're planning to develop also in the other languages than Android accomodated Java, please free to download for example: 
`Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers`

I had used `Eclipse for Eclipse`Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers 4.5.1` and 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers', so I'm sure these are higly compatible with newet ADT Plugin.

---

After you install Eclipse, you need to download and unpack `Stand-alone SDK Tools`, where you would find [here] http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

**Note**: Already the latest version of Android SDK is `android-sdk_r24.4.1`.

After downloading and unpack `Eclipse` and `Android SDK` read this documentation:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html or just follow these steps:

> ## To add the ADT plugin to Eclipse:
>
> 1. Start `Eclipse`, then select `Help > Install New Software`.
> 2. Click `Add`, in the top-right corner.
> 3. In the `Add Repository` dialog that appears, enter
>      `ADT Plugin` for the `Name` and the following `URL` for the `Location`:  `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
>
> > **Note:** The Android Developer
> >     Tools update site requires a secure connection. Make sure the update
> >     site URL you enter starts with HTTPS.
>
> 4. Click `OK`.
> 5. In the `Available Software` dialog, select the **checkbox** next
>      to `Developer Tools` and click `Next`.
> 6. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded.
> 7. Click `Next`.
> 8. Read and accept the license agreements, then click `Finish`. 
>      If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click `OK`. 
>      When the installation completes, **restart** Eclipse.

---

> ## Configure the ADT Plugin
>
> Once Eclipse **restarts**, you **must specify the
>   location** of your `Android SDK directory`:
>
> 1. In the "Welcome to Android Development" window that appears, select `Use existing SDKs`.
> 2. Browse and select the location of the Android SDK directory you recently downloaded and unpacked.
> 3. Click `Next`.
> 4. **Your Eclipse IDE is now set up to develop Android apps, but you need to add the latest SDK platform tools and an Android platform to your
>      environment**.
> 5. To get these packages for your SDK, continue to [Adding
>      Platforms and Packages](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html).

Answer (score 5):

In July 2017, Eclipse Oxygen is out and ADT is weakly supported (or unsupported).  But it's still often necessary to get these working together properly (reasons vary).  Here are instruction to bring up an Eclipse Oxygen (latest at the time of writing) with the ADT on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 (latest LTS at time).

1. I started from a clean install of Ubuntu
2. Install OpenJDK 8
   `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`
3. I needed OpenJDK 7 for my project (skip if not needed)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
   ```
4. Download Eclipse Oxygen (I chose the Java bundle) and install.
5. Run Eclipse and close the welcome screen, get to the place where there is a blank workspase
6. In your browser, go the Eclipse Marketplace where the ADT is provided.  At the time of writing, it was [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/android-development-tools-eclipse).
7. Drag the "Install" button from the web page to the workstation pane in the running Eclipse (size your windows so that you can see both).  The cursor will have a plus sign when dragged over the correct place.  Then "drop"/release the icon.  The install should proceed from there.
8. Eclipse will ask to restart, do so.
9. No Android SDK will be found, follow the prompts to get one setup.
10. The SDK Build Tools may be out of date, causing an error, but ADT will prompt to install the latest, follow the prompts.
11. I had an ADB error in the log window until I finished setting up the SDK and tool and then restarted Eclipse.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here I am, deciding that I wanted to try out Eclipse again, needing ADT. I stumbled upon this answer, seeing that it was only 4 hours old. And to my surprise, you are using the exact same OS and requirements. The internet is wonderful at times.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get an updated version of the ADT plugin that adds support for the latest NDK and fixes some bugs related to native C/C++ debugging at: https://github.com/khaledev/ADT

Answer (score -1):

For the installation of Android ADT at Eclipse, do the following:

1. HELP > INSTALL NEW SOFTWARE > ADD > NAME (AS YOUR WISH)
2. LOCATION > copy and paste the link: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ > OK
3. SELECT OR CLICK DEVELOPER TOOLS > FINISH

Then automatically it will install android plugins (for application development). Afterwards, restart for the better convenience. 
Thank you.