# Javafx app crashes when running on android phone

Tags: javafx

I converted a hello world javafx  .jar into .apk using eclipse,  gluon and gradle, I successfully installed it on an android phone,  but it's not working, it crashes anytime I try to run it. It shows "unfortunately, MyHelloWorldApp has stopped". Please, how should I fix this?

Comment: With your mobile connected to your PC, and with debugging options enabled on your device, go to command line, cd into android SDK/platform tools, and run: `adb logcat -v threadtime`. Then run your app, and find in the terminal the exception that causes the crash, and try to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to debug a javafx application for android in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075592/how-to-debug-a-javafx-application-for-android-in-eclipse)