# What is the Last Version of the Eclipse ADT plugin

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

I have always coded android apps using eclipse as opposed to android studio simply because i find it faster than android studio. However because google has deprecated eclipse as the official IDE for android.They also stopped developing android developer tools (ADT) plugin.

For purposes of the layout renderer in eclipse, I need to know what was the last version of Android Developer Tools plugin for eclipse to be ever released by google before it was deprecated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install last version of ADT plug-in for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301997/how-to-install-last-version-of-adt-plug-in-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

The last version of ADT tools should be [`ADT-23.0.7`](https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-23.0.7.zip).

I've never managed to find something newer than that.

In the [official annoucement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html) it states:

> Android tools inside Eclipse will continue to live on in the open source community via the Eclipse Foundation. Check out the latest Eclipse [Andmore project](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore) if you are interested in contributing or learning more.